# NXP LPC1114 UART doesn't work after reset

Tags: uart, ftdi, lpc, lpcxpresso

I'm building a simple circuit with [LPC1114](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC111X.pdf) to make a "hello world" application using UART. Trying to write all the code from scratch, to have a better understanding on what's happening.

My problem is that UART only works only after flashing (i.e. when lpc21isp asks MCU to start running code). The same code doesn't work if MCU is reset.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
void platform_uart_setup(uint32_t baud_rate) // 9600
{
  // Make sure UART IRQ is disabled
  NVIC_DisableIRQ(UART_IRQn);

  // Setup pin 1_6 as RXD
  LPC_IOCON->PIO1_6 &= ~0x07;
  LPC_IOCON->PIO1_6 |= 0x01;

  // Setup pin 1_7 as TXD
  LPC_IOCON->PIO1_7 &= ~0x07;
  LPC_IOCON->PIO1_7 |= 0x01;

  // Enable & configure UART clock
  LPC_SYSCON->SYSAHBCLKCTRL |= (1<<12);
  LPC_SYSCON->UARTCLKDIV = 0x1;

  // Setup format: 8N1, enable access to divisor latches
  LPC_UART->LCR = 0x83;

  // Setup baud rate, which is based on system clock
  uint32_t Fdiv = platform_clock // take cpu clock (12000000 in this case)
      / LPC_SYSCON->SYSAHBCLKDIV // divide by ABH clock
      / LPC_SYSCON->UARTCLKDIV // divide further by UART clock
      / 16 // divisor latch is 16x the desired baud rate
      / baud_rate;

  LPC_UART->DLM = Fdiv / 256;
  LPC_UART->DLL = Fdiv % 256;

  LPC_UART->FDR = 0x00 | (1 << 4) | 0;

  // Enable and reset FIFOs
  LPC_UART->FCR = 0x07;

  // Disable access to divisor latches
  LPC_UART->LCR = 0x03;

  // Read to reset LSR
  volatile uint32_t unused = LPC_UART->LSR;

  // Make sure there's no data
  while(( LPC_UART->LSR & (0x20|0x40)) != (0x20|0x40) )
    ;
  while( LPC_UART->LSR & 0x01 ) {
    unused = LPC_UART->RBR;
  }

  // Enable UART IRQ
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(UART_IRQn);

  // We don't care about interrupts for now
  LPC_UART->IER = 0;
}

void platform_uart_putc(const char c)
{
  while( !(LPC_UART->LSR & 0x20) )
    ;
  LPC_UART->THR = c;
}
```

On after the reset there are absolutely no signal changes on TXD pin.

Comment: Can you show the circuit? This May be due to a jumper set on **boot from 'x'** as oppose to **boot from 'y'**

Comment: Well, if I add up a few leds and blink them in `platform_uart_putc` it blinks, so the code gets executed. The circuit is pretty simple, it's just RXD/TXD to FTDI, and two buttons for reset and 1.1 bootloader entry pin.

Comment: thank you so much. I don't know how, but by projects stopped working after some time. UART simply didn't send nothing. I don't know why IOCON was disabled to everything. I added it on System init and averything was resolved!

Comment: If you're using `system_LPC11xx.h` you can also use `SystemCoreClock` after calling `SystemInit` and `SystemCoreClockUpdate`. It contains the core clock frequency (although with a default set-up probably 12000000).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to enable the clock to IOCON before configuring the pins for UART use, hence those assignments have no effect. But after a bootload the pins are already configured for UART, so things work.

Insert

```
LPC_SYSCON->SYSAHBCLKCTRL |= (1<<16); // enable IOCON
```

after the IRQ setting, before configuring the pins.

PS my [bmptk](http://www.voti.nl/bmptk) library supports the LPC1114. It is in C++, but you might take a look at the GPIO pins configuration (and UART initialization!), check targert/cortex/lpc1114fn28.h, and the timer initialization in targets/cortex/lpc1114.cpp

Comment: I can't find `lpc1114.cpp` in your BMPTK. A search for `LPC_UART` didn't turn up anything. Another question, could you point me to where the user manual states where `IOCON` has to be enabled?

Comment: IIRC that is not mentioned in the description of the periopherals itself, only in the description of the SYSCON register.